# Is there a way to make a sharable link to a video uploaded locally in HTML?

Tags: html, video, hyperlink, share

I'm learning how to write more in-depth code, and decided to start a project that I'm interested in to entice myself to pay more attention. I want to make my own website where I upload clips I made of my friends and I playing games. I understand how to put a local video into HTML code, but is there a way to make separate sharable links for each one? This way instead of sending a link to just the site, I can link the specific video that I want to share. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share any progress or attempts you have made? Stack Overflow is not here to develop projects for you.

Comment: Hi @Blake I have made 0 progress because I haven't started yet! Just asking if there is a way to do what I mentioned in the question, I have every intention of doing it myself, that's the whole point! If you know how to make individual video links, I'd love to know how, if you do not know how, I'll keep waiting for someone who can give a real answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would put videos on separate pages like:

```
testdomain.com/video1.html
testdomain.com/video2.html
...
```

This would be the most simplest and straight way to do so at the beginning, but also the least recommendable.

I suggest you to learn about [back-end programming](https://www.conceptatech.com/blog/difference-front-end-back-end-development) (since you already had begun with the front-end side), and [databases](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_intro.asp). And then how these are related with the [MVC model](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm), to get a full website and achieve your goal in the best way possible.

Comment: I think looking into some form of back-end programming. This actually gave me an idea to implement a search/filter feature, to either search by a video's title or filter them by their upload date! Thank you for the tip!